# How to access multiple Azure subscription through SPN in Azure Devops CICD?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I have created SPN for Azure devops pipeline and I need to access multiple subscription resources in a powershell task/deploymentScript ARM.I am using below command to switch between subscriptions

```
 #Linking appinsight with storage account in Secondary Region 
    Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $secSubscriptionId | Set-AzContext
```

This command works from my local powershell (as I have access to both subscriptions). But with CICD another subscription is not visible.I get below error even though both subs are under same tenant.

```
2020-05-12T17:17:14.9377680Z ##[error]Subscription XXXXXXX was not found in tenant ***. Please verify that the subscription exists in this tenant.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you created the service principal, did you give it access to resources in both subscriptions?

Comment: actually I am not aware of this option.Do you have any documentation link?

Comment: I'm not sure i have the documentation for that, but i assume you created the app registration (service principal) for devops to access your 1st azure subscription. so you should be able to add that to the second subscription as either a contributor or reader(depending on what you need to do). so. azure portal-> search for subscriptions -> click on second sub -> click access control -> click add. -> find the app registration for the devops/powershell sp -> choose either contributor or reader. -> Add.. that should give the devops access to the second subscription.